# Redirect one url to another url using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

As i am trying to redirect one complete URL

```
http://www.domain-name.com/download/?page=download
```

To this URL

```
http://www.domain-name.com/download/show
```

For this to work I have added this code

```
rewriterule http://www.domain.com/download/?page=download(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/download/show$1 [r=301,nc]
```

But this is not working and instead it says the URL I am requesting says "Forbidden".

Can any one please give any solution for this.

Comment: Where does show come from? Should it always be added or not? Can you explain the rules you want to apply to the url more clear?

Answer (score 25):

Redirect One URL to Another URL by Using htaccess file:

```
Redirect 301 /en/php/project.html http://www.example.org/newpage.html
```

Answer (score 7):

RewriteRule doesn't include the query string and doesn't include the http-host. Besides that, the first argument is a regex pattern. Without the http host you would be matching either `download/page=download(etc)` or `downloadpage=download(etc)`.

You'll need 2 rules. One that redirects the ugly url to the nice url. One rule needs to rewrite the nice url to an actual working url:

```
#Rewrite ugly url to nice url
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=download&?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^download/?$ download/show?%1 [R,L]

#Now get the nice url to work:
RewriteRule ^download/show/?$ download/?page=download [QSA,END]
```

The second rule uses the QSA flag, which means it will append the original query string to the query string in the rewriterule. The END flag stops all rewriting, as the L-flag doesn't do that in .htaccess context. END is only available from Apache 2.3.9 onwards and will cause an internal server error if used in an version before that. Please note that you probably have to modify the second rule to point to an actual file.

You can find the documentation [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

*Edit: Please note that you should NEVER test htaccess rules with a PERMANENT redirect. If you make a mistake, the browser will remember this mistake! Only convert temporary redirects to permanent redirects if everything is working as you expect it to work.*

Comment: @Prix Read the entire thing and you'll see exactly why that is... This code is tested... and works on Apache 2.3.9 onwards

Comment: Mine is 2.4.6 and I just placed your rule for a test drive.

Comment: @Prix Proof it works [in 2.4.4 here](http://www.screenr.com/wFAH). It must be your end then... or there are undocumented changes in 2.4.6 I am not aware of.

Comment: @Sumurai8 Thanks for your immediate response.. Actually the thing is that, this is the old url http://www.domain-name.com/download/?page=download which already promoted and bookmarked but recently we have changed the complete script and url structure also changed because of some issues and the new url looks like this http://www.domain-name.com/download/show. As i have tried your code but its throwing "Internal Server Error"...Can you please suggest me in this regard.

Comment: Assuming you read my entire answer and it isn't a problem with your Apache version: Use `LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3` in your httpd.conf and find out what is causing this error.

Comment: @phphunger Also make sure you have `RewriteBase /` set.

Answer (score 5):

you can use this rule

```
Redirect /download/?page=download http://www.domain-name.com/download/show
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `RewriteEngine`:

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 http://www.domain-name.com/download/?page=download http://www.domain-name.com/download/show
```