# redirect a specific url to another url with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I would like to have an alias and redirect the URL `tz433.tld/jobs/` to the page `tz433.tld/about-us/jobs/`.

This is what I've tried by far; it didn't work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.tz433\.tld/jobs/$
RewriteRule (.*) http://tz433.tld/about-us/jobs.html [R=301,L]
```

The problem is, in this root path there are multiple domains, because it is a multisite typo3 installation. So something like "redirect `/jobs` to `/about-us/jobs`" isn't working because it should only happen for a specific domain (tz433).

The next specific thing is `www.tz433.tld` automatically redirects to `tz433.tld`. So it should also work with `www.tz433.tld/jobs/` and `tz433.tld/jobs`. Both should redirect to `tz433.tld/about-us/jobs.html`.

How can I achieve that successfully?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect one url to another url using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18030491/redirect-one-url-to-another-url-using-htaccess)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want the rule to only execute when the domain is *"tz433.tld"*, you need this condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?tz433\.tld
```

And to redirect *"jobs/"* and *"jobs"* to *"tz433.tld/about-us/jobs.html"*, you can try one of these:

```
RewriteRule ^jobs/? /about-us/jobs.html [R=301,L]
# or
RewriteRule ^jobs/? http://tz433.tld/about-us/jobs.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: @5ervant i want to do same but your solution isn't working for me i'm using wordpress though and i want to redirect a url if it has `/for-your-practice/`, can you please tell what could go wrong ? This is what i did 
`RewriteRule ^for-your-practice/? /product-category/for-your-practice [R=301,L]`

Comment: @HabibRehman To redirect _www.example.com/for-your-practice/_ to _www.example.com/product-category/for-your-practice_ you can use your directive. (Check your other directives if they have conflict to that directive.) To redirect all _www.example.com/for-your-practice/anything_ pages to _www.example.com/product-category/for-your-practice_ you can use `RewriteRule ^for-your-practice/(.*) /product-category/for-your-practice [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 19):

If someone is just interested in simple redirect you can try this:

```
Redirect /URL URLtoRedirect
```

e.g

```
Redirect /old-url https://mywebsite.com/new-url
```

Comment: Maybe I'm doing it wrong but this doesn't work for me. Don't I need to use a redirect condition before this?

Comment: @eLeMeNOhPi No you need nothing just put the above line of code in your htaccess and that's it.