# Redirect Specific URi to Specific URi on the same host

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Any help regarding the topic will be much appreciate!

What we are trying to do is this :

This link : http://www.example.com/?ModuleVal=SomeDetails&Stdold=1287 we need to redirect to this link: http://www.example.com/?ModuleVal=SomeDetails&StdoId=2862 via .htaccess

How can we properly configure this kind of redirection/rewrite?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [redirect a specific url to another url with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31829149/redirect-a-specific-url-to-another-url-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try it:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ModuleVal=SomeDetails&Stdold=1287$
    RewriteRule ^/?$ /?ModuleVal=SomeDetails&Stdold=2862 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```