# Redirect to a specific URL on page load JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, redirect, page-replacement

I have a problem with redirection. What I am trying to do is:
"When a specific page off one website is loaded, it should redirect to another page/URL in the same window".

I have this code

```
window.onload = function() {
  location.href = "https://www.javascripttutorial.net/";
}
```

But the problem is where am I going to put my old URL which should be redirected because I am redirecting only a specific page to another website.

Kindly help me out with this.

Comment: Hi Asaad, always try to break down the issue you have into its parts. Note that the actual problem you have has nothing to do with redirection, it's only about figuring out what the current URL is. And you already have what you need: `location.href`

Comment: If it is just one specific URL I wouldn't do this on client side with javascript. This is something your Webservers vhost file should take care of.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
if (location.href.indexOf('oldpage') !=-1) 
  location.replace("https://www.javascripttutorial.net/")
```

which will not break the user's back button

However: It sounds like you should add the url in the `.htaccess`  and have the server do the redirect instead: [redirect a specific url to another url with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31829149/redirect-a-specific-url-to-another-url-with-htaccess)

Comment: Cheers! This works fine for me, I have some parameters with the old URL, despite what parameter I have It only grabs the base URL and redirects to the new one.

Comment: location.href contains the full URL including parameters