# PHP preg_match regex redirect url

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I working on a Laravel app and I have these links :

```
http://mywebsite.com/content/*
http://mywebsite.com/products/*
http://mywebsite.com/search/node*
http://mywebsite.com/user/*
http://mywebsite.com/escal/list/*
http://mywebsite.com/node/*
http://mywebsite.com/download/file/fid/*
```

I need to redirect these link patterns to the home page : http://mywebsite.com/

I have a middleware where I tried to put all the links in an array, I loop through the array while taking the path after `.com/` and using `substr` to test if it startsWith `request()->path()`. But I think it should be done using regex `preg_match` but I have no clue how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If this is very important, i prefer to you handle this with htaccess, its very faster than laravel. example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18030491/redirect-one-url-to-another-url-using-htaccess

Answer (score 1):

```
$paths = [
'content',
'products',
'search\/node',
'user',
'escal\/list',
'node',
'download\/file\/fid',
];

$patternWithPaths = sprintf('/^http:\/\/mywebsite\.com\/(%s)\//', implode('|', $paths));

if(preg_match($patternWithPaths))
{
  // A match was found, do redirect.
}
```

Comment: I don't want to mention `mywebsite`, I'll have access to only the `request()->path()`, which returns the part after `.com/`, and I also like I mentioned, I need to redirect `content/*` meaning paths like `content/test` should be redirected.